# Not able to receive response from my xml file when a post request is sent to it

Tags: php

This my exact code below:

```
<?php 


$slipno = $_POST['slipno'];


$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$database = "payment"; 



//connect to the database
$db = new mysqli('deeperlifehighschool.ipagemysql.com', $user, $password, $database );
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

//query the database    
          $sqlQuery = "select * FROM transactions where slipno='$slipno'";

//run query
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sqlQuery)) {

Header('Content-type: text/xml');

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

echo '<response>';



//fetch associative array 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<result>';
       echo '<school>' . htmlspecialchars($row["school"]) . '</school>';
       echo '<slipno>' . htmlspecialchars($row["slipno"]) . '</slipno>';
       echo '<pincode>' . htmlspecialchars($row["pincode"]) . '</pincode>';
       echo '<damount>' . htmlspecialchars($row["damount"]) . '</damount>';
       echo '<dchild>' . htmlspecialchars($row["dchild"]) . '</dchild>';
       echo '<dphoneno>' . htmlspecialchars($row["dphoneno"]) . '</dphoneno>';
       echo '<email>' . htmlspecialchars($row["email"]) . '</email>';
       echo '<dpay>' . htmlspecialchars($row["dpay"]) . '</dpay>';
       echo '<dname>' . htmlspecialchars($row["dname"]) . '</dname>';




}

echo '</result>';

}

//close the database connection
$db->close();

echo '</response>';
?>
```

This is the response i am  getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<result></result>
</response>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The titel of the question is not meant to be the place to ask the question. Please formulate a suitable titel that describes your problem.

Comment: Firstly check that your query is even retrieving any data (you should also be using prepared statements).  Secondly is that you should be building the XML using a library (simplexml should be enough here) as in the code - your tags are improperly nested (start of result in the loop, end outside the loop.

Comment: check your result set and put this line echo '</result>'; inside while loop

Answer (score 0):

You created a MySQL connection in an object-oriented way, but your query is a procedural query.

In [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php#example-1859):

> It is possible to switch between styles at any time. Mixing both
>   styles is not recommended for code clarity and coding style reasons.

Second, it's highly recommended you use prepared statements when you interact with database.

Third, the opening of `result` tree is inside `while` loop, but closing is outside. And as @Nigel Ren stated, you can use XML library ([SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)).

```
<?php

$slipno = $_POST['slipno'];

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$database = "payment";

$db = new mysqli('deeperlifehighschool.ipagemysql.com', $user, $password, $database);

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE slipno = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $slipno);

$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<response></response>');

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $r = $xml->addChild('result');
    $r->addChild('slipno', htmlspecialchars($result['slipno']));
    $r->addChild('pincode', htmlspecialchars($result['pincode']));
    $r->addChild('damount', htmlspecialchars($result['damount']));
    $r->addChild('dchild', htmlspecialchars($result['dchild']));
    $r->addChild('dphoneno', htmlspecialchars($result['dphoneno']));
    $r->addChild('email', htmlspecialchars($result['email']));
    $r->addChild('dpay', htmlspecialchars($result['dpay']));
    $r->addChild('dname', htmlspecialchars($result['dname']));
}

header('Content-type: text/xml');

echo $xml->asXML();

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: I have tried the above without success yet any help

Comment: It is returning blank page when i query the page using postman.